# Efficient symmetrical matrix data readout

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a `df` filled with a symmetrical matrix of data. Now I want to extract data labels (positions of data) witch are above some value. In normal "for-loop" thinking, I'd do something like this:

```
for j in range(df.shape[0]): 
    for i in range(j):
        if (df.iloc[j, i] >= value):
            print(df.index.values[i]) #do something
            print(df.index.values[j])
```

I had this approach with two for loops, which was working really well. The problem with this was that it is way too slow. The data size can vary and have a few hundred or thousands of columns and rows. Therefore I would like to use a efficient way to process the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

value = 0.6

df = pd.DataFrame(squareform(np.random.rand(10)))

print(df)

result = []

for j in range(df.shape[0]):
    result = np.where(value <= df.loc[j, :]) 


    for element in range(len(result[0])):
        print(result[0][element]) # do something
```

This basically works. But my problem is now that I don't understand how to ignore the one symmetrical side of the matrix since I only need half of the matrix for further progressing.

`numpy.where()` does speed up the process, but it is giving me some confusion since it reads out one whole line of `df` and I don't know how to proceed proberly. I'd get double positions if I'd use `result` as it is which is unnecessary.

Is there maybe a thing I just don't see? Or maybe an even better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean numpy ndenumerate? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html

Comment: this is a good suggestion, but it doesn't solve the problem of the symmetrical values in the matrix

Comment: by index condition  j >= i , you can ignore one symmetrical side

Answer (score 0):

numpy ndenumerate

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 4, 5]
])

for (i, j), v in np.ndenumerate(df):
    do something
```